# Save status in @before method, do the @test, then rollback the changes in @after

Tags: java, spring, junit

I was wondering if this is possible. This is my first question so bear with me if I do not exactly follow protocol. I am able to rollback my transactions with a transaction template. But now what I want to do is save a status in the method labeled @before and then roll it back in the @after method.

For example this is what I had before:

```
      _transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
            @Override
     protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus transactionStatus)
     {

                Object transactionStatusSavepoint = transactionStatus.createSavepoint();
                //do some work
                transactionStatus.rollbackToSavepoint(transactionStatusSavepoint);
      }
     });
```

This all works well and good. Now I would like to do this:

```
@Before
    public void beforeTest() {
        _template.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {

            @Override
            protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus transactionStatus) {

                _transactionStatusSavepoint = _transactionStatus.createSavepoint();
            }
        });

@Test
public void foo(){//do some stuff}

@After
    public void afterTest() {
    _transactionStatus.rollbackToSavepoint(_transactionStatusSavepoint);
}
```

Please let me know if you do not understand or would like to elaborate more.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: So what is the problem? The code does not work? An error is thrown?

Comment: An error is thrown. "Invalid argument in JDBC call: 3B001 savepoint exception: invalid specification".

"Could not roll back to JDBC savepoint; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument in JDBC call: 3B001 savepoint exception: invalid specification
 at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.JdbcTransactionObjectSupport.rollbackToSavepoint(JdbcTransactionObjectSupport.java:132)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transaction status will not be valid once doInTransactionWithoutResult is complete, so you cannot use it in your afterTest method.

It looks like you are using spring for your test.  Spring comes with test runner that can rollback a transaction when your tests complete.

[Spring testing](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-tx)

Comment: Why can't you save off the transaction status in a global variable? I am quite new to spring and will probably accept this answer, but I would just like to know.

Comment: @publ1c_stat1c The execute method in the TransactionTemplate commits the transaction if the TransactionCallback does not throw an exception. If an exception is thrown then the transaction is rollback.  So you cannot rollback a transaction that is already committed.